# Showing attachment on data list on microsoft power pages

Tags: html, view, powerbi, drag-and-drop, powerapps

Need help on showing attachment on my main power pages listing page, Till now It is showing on power apps view but I need to show all the listing including my uploaded attachment on my listing page so that client can download on the main pages.
[image]

[image]

Need to show above image pdf or image file on below listing page so that client can download this file from my production server directly.